# display second dropdown values based on first dropdown selection in angular 8, material

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pull the data and bind that data in the drodown and based on the selection of first dropdown i want to populate the second dropdown. For that i have written the below code. But i am not getting the proper output. Instead i am getting the errors. Please review my code as i am very new to Angular. Below is my json data from where i am getting the data.

This is my http service method:

```
getAccountByApiGateway(accountType: string) {
    return this.http.get(this.serviceUrl + "/account-type/" + accountType);
  }
```

The below is my JSON data:

```
{
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "8a8080fc710cdc140171104216c2002b",
          "name": "a",
          "org": {
            "id": "8a8080c4701e557501701e6cbeed003e",
            "orgPlan": "ENTERPRISE"
          },
          "accountType": "AWS"
        },
        {
          "id": "8a80802c712a8e8301712ad32c540001",
          "name": "azure",
          "org": {
            "id": "8a8080c4701e557501701e6cbeed003e",
            "orgPlan": "ENTERPRISE"
          },
          "accountType": "AZURE"
        },
        {
          "id": "8a80802c712a8e8301712b177d2e0002",
          "name": "aws2",
          "org": {
            "id": "8a8080c4701e557501701e6cbeed003e",
            "orgPlan": "ENTERPRISE"
          },
          "accountType": "AWS"
        },
        {
          "id": "8a80802c712a8e8301712b7c3b5a0003",
          "name": "FX AWS",
          "org": {
            "id": "8a8080c4701e557501701e6cbeed003e",
            "orgPlan": "ENTERPRISE"
          },
          "accountType": "AWS"
        }
      ],
      "totalPages": 0,
      "totalElements": 0
    }
```

The below is my component data

```
    accountTypes: Type[] = [
        { value: "AWS", viewValue: "AWS" },
        { value: "AZURE", viewValue: "AZURE" }
      ];

ngOnInit() {
this.getApiGatewayAccounts();
}
changeIssueTracker(type) {
    if (type.value === "AWS") {
      this.job.issueTracker.accountType = "AWS";
    } else if (type.value === "AZURE") {
      this.job.issueTracker.accountType = "AZURE";
    }
    this.getApiGatewayAccounts();
  }
getApiGatewayAccounts() {
    this.handler.activateLoader();
    this.apiGatewayService.getAccountByApiGateway("API_GATEWAY").subscribe(
      results => {
        this.handler.hideLoader();
        if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
          return;
        }
        this.apiAccounts = results['data'];
      },
      error => {
        this.handler.hideLoader();
        this.handler.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

My template code is below:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
                                <mat-select name="cloudString" placeholder="Select API Gateway">
                                    <mat-option disabled>--- Select API Gateway ---</mat-option>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accountTypes" [value]="account.value" (click)="changeIssueTracker(type)">
                                        <span *ngIf="account.value=='AWS'">
                                            <img class="img-responsive h-75" src="assets/images/aws-small.png" />
                                        </span>
                                        <span *ngIf="account.value=='AZURE'">
                                            <img class="img-responsive h-75" src="assets/images/azure-small.png" />
                                        </span>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ account.value}}</mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                                <mat-select name="cloudString2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let account of apiAccounts" [value]="account.name">
                                        {{account.name}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

I am getting the below error when i click on the first dropdown

```
core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at ApiGatewayComponent.push../src/app/components/manage/api-gateway/api-gateway.component.ts.ApiGatewayComponent.changeIssueTracker
```

Comment: where is `type` being defined in your `*ngFor*` loop? should it be `account. accountType `?

Comment: Actually i am trying to change the change the 2nd dropdown values based on 1st dropdown selection so for that i have added the (click)="changeIssueTracker(type)" function. I am not clear how that change happens when i click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-option
  *ngFor="let account of accountTypes"
  [value]="account.value"
  (click)="changeIssueTracker(type)">
```

Your issue is that `type` is not defined.

```
<mat-option
      *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes"
      [value]="accountType.value"
      (click)="changeIssueTracker(accountType)">
      <span *ngIf="accountType.value=='AWS'">
        <img class="img-responsive h-75" src="assets/images/aws-small.png" />
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="accountType.value=='AZURE'">
        <img class="img-responsive h-75" src="assets/images/azure-small.png" />
      </span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ accountType.value}}
</mat-option>
```

As far as binding data to the second dropdown, you will need to filter the data you get from the api and iterate over that new list in your form field. You already have the concept in place for an unfiltered list of the API data. Something like this in your `.component.ts`

```
filteredAccountsByType = [];

changeIssueTracker(type: AccountType): void {
  if (type.value === "AWS") {
    this.job.issueTracker.accountType = "AWS";
  } else if (type.value === "AZURE") {
    this.job.issueTracker.accountType = "AZURE";
  }
  this.filteredAccountsByType = this.apiAccounts.filter(apiAccount => apiAccount.accountType === type.value);
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, Actually the first dropdown is working for me but the issue is with the 2nd dropdown . I am trying to populate the 2nd dropdown on selection of 1st one. Similar to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-select-dynamic-data-binding-in-angular?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html

Comment: The error you had points to the first drop down. Is this comment additional to the original proglem?

Comment: Yes, of course, the problem is with the 2nd dropdown. I am trying to display the corresponding values of 1st dropdown selection.

Comment: For example,  "accountType": "AWS" then for this we have "name": "a","name": "aws2", and "name": "FX AWS" so i want to show all these 3 on selecting AWS from 1st dropdown. Similarly "accountType": "AZURE" we have "name": "azure". So i want to display Azure related data (name). How to bind this data on clicking 1st dropdown?

Comment: That sounds like an new question outside of the original of fixing the error you ran into.

Comment: No, actually it was my original question, the solution which you have posted is already working for me. But on clicking the 1st dropdown i want to populate the 2nd dropdown.

Comment: this.filteredAccountsByType = this.apiAccounts.filter(apiAccount => apiAccount.accountType = type.value); What is apiAccount in the above statement?

Comment: Read up on the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of an Array.

Comment: Any luck with this? If it solved your question(s), its best to mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Andrew, it got fixed and i modified the code with yours. Thanks for your timely support.